# Vb.net Set focus to nested control on another open form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a form that I open from a menu item on my main form that has a datagridview that contains a control name. When I click on the control name I'd like it to set focus back to the main form and focus the control. I can get it to work if the control name is a control on the current tab, but if I try to focus to a control on another tab on my main form it does not focus. I don't get an error, it just doesn't focus.

Any assistance you could give me to point me in the right direction would be most appreciated. Thanks

My main form consists of nested controls:

Tabcontrol
  Tabpage 
     Groupbox 
        Control (such as textbox, etc)

Here is my code from the 2nd form:

```
Public Property f1 As MainForm

   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick


        For Each cont As Control In f1.Controls

            For Each Tp As TabPage In cont.Controls

                For Each gbx As GroupBox In Tp.Controls

                    For Each ctrl As Control In gbx.Controls


                        If ctrl.Name = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(1).Value Then
                            ctrl.Focus()
                            Exit For
                        End If




                    Next ctrl

                Next gbx

            Next Tp

        Next cont

        Me.Close()

end sub
```

Comment: try setting focus to the correct tab and then to the control.

Comment: That works. Is there any way I can set the tabcontrol.selectedindex without using the actual name of the tabcontrol. I'd like to use the with other forms. I can change my Public Property f1 As Form as assign the form name, but how can I go about setting the selected index on the tab without specifying an actual tabcontrol name?

Comment: Thanks - you have pointed me in the right direction.